# Installation problem of Virtual Treview in Embarcadero RAD Studio XE

Tags: installation, virtualtreeview, c++builder-xe

I heard that Virtual Tree view is the best tree view for Embarcadero RAD Studio on Stac Overflow.

So i have downloaded Virtual Treeview Setup 4.8.7.exe from its website & installed.

It showed  that it installs without any errors but it do not shows in IDE i have tried many things but failed  & asked to author but no reply

So anybody has the solution please give me

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and it seems to be solved by installing Delphi Package from the installation path, file Delphi13d worked for me.